# I'm having a problem with a 301 redirect I can't find

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have no idea why my robots.txt is being redirected to my homepage.

My website runs on WordPress and I use Cloudflare's DNS.

I have already tried disabling all plugins, clearing all cache on Cloudflare, changing theme, changing my .htaccess file back to standard, but it keeps redirecting me even with cache cleard.

Can you guys help me find any possible solution?

> https://ajudacorporal.com.br/robots.txt
>
> HTTP/2 301  date: Sat, 12 Feb 2022 21:19:20 GMT
> content-type:
> text/html; charset=UTF-8 location: https://ajudacorporal.com.br/
> x-redirect-by: WordPress cache-control: max-age=0 expires: Sat, 12 Feb
> 2022 21:19:20 GMT vary: Accept-Encoding cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC
> expect-ct: max-age=604800,
> report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
> report-to:
> {"endpoints":[{"url":"https://a.nel.cloudflare.com/report/v3?s=gP%2BCCf3mXEvzpRaxDw5qVR5no3NSOeRixlw4nCXWsDt7hBre3o5cllvDDQ6xB8YbhoO966d43S57h8M2627DoM1LqImRtGqrNGExjHKAsbQ1u7o2QaXdRzomRZARf%2FCRTKSpg727Kg%3D%3D"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
> nel: {"success_fraction":0,"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
> server: cloudflare cf-ray: 6dc8dac89be17e94-LAX alt-svc: h3=":443";
> ma=86400, h3-29=":443"; ma=86400
>
> https://ajudacorporal.com.br/
>
> HTTP/2 200  date: Sat, 12 Feb 2022 21:19:21 GMT content-type:
> text/html; charset=UTF-8 last-modified: Sat, 12 Feb 2022 21:16:56 GMT
> cache-control: max-age=0 expires: Sat, 12 Feb 2022 21:19:21 GMT vary:
> Accept-Encoding cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC expect-ct: max-age=604800,
> report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
> report-to:
> {"endpoints":[{"url":"https://a.nel.cloudflare.com/report/v3?s=dBtDH8OS021x3CNcIqjL0B6FgmfRcvKmiU1a%2FxiNPMRFPoD8Vs%2B7pBDGv7lnNy8jp1Q75gKG6RLCk5cActMuWD%2FNktKZeRFS3oMioDB47GLpJ1vQNDIMHPnrQknVvSytMYm%2ByNJAhA%3D%3D"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
> nel: {"success_fraction":0,"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
> server: cloudflare cf-ray: 6dc8dace39547acf-LAX alt-svc: h3=":443";
> ma=86400, h3-29=":443"; ma=86400

These are the traces for the redirect.

Comment: See 'x-redirect-by' for the source of redirection

Answer (score 0):

The described issue might be caused due to many different factors, considering the fact that you:

1. Use Cloudflare
2. Use cache plugins
3. Your host might also have a cache interfering with that
4. Or you might be completely missing robots.txt

Certainly, you will receive much more accurate answers from your hosting provider. I would recommend reaching them out ."